# How to stop Github Desktop from changing my line endings

Tags: git, github, line-endings, github-desktop

I'm pretty sure Github Desktop is changing my line endings when I commit the files, how do I turn this feature off? I'm using blazor and the files need to remain unchanged or they will fail blazors integrity checks

I've read that git config core.autocrlf = false should work, but where does that command run?

I'm new to Git, and I use the Github Desktop instead of having to deal with all the command line stuff that I don't understand

I really wish it would stop trying to be "helpful" and just leave my damn code alone...

Help...

Comment: _"but where does that command run"_ - in the terminal or command prompt.

Comment: really? that simple. I get command not found, the Github Desktop is a PWA so it must not have brought the exe with it

Comment: Do you have "git bash" installed? If so, consider using that instead of command prompt.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid learning git, that's why I went for the GUI, problem is that it tries to be helpful and hides behind layers of magic. I'll check it out, thankyou

Comment: Never avoid learning git. You don't need to learn the commands, but definitely learn the concepts it uses.

Answer (score 12):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/10666) regarding GitHub Desktop not picking up system-level git config but setting the global configs should work. You can use the command line to set it with `git config --global core.autocrlf false` but given you want to avoid the command line you can also edit the config file directly. It is located in your home directory (`C:\Users\USER_NAME\.gitconfig` on Windows).

Edit the file and add autocrlf in the core config:

```
[core]
    autocrlf = false
```

Before you continue with this make sure you also understand line endings and what `autocrlf` does (docs: [8.1 Customizing Git - Git Configuration](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration)). In short:

- `false`: git does not change anything (only use it if your code is used only on Windows)
- `input`: git converts CRLF (Windows) to LF (Linux, MacOS) on commit
- `true`: git converts LF to CRLF on checkout

If you want to enforce certain standards in your git repository have a look at [gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes).

Answer (score 4):

> I've read that git config core.autocrlf = false should work, but where does that command run?

Start with:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

That should be enough for GitHub Desktop to not change the eol.